# orWhere in a relationship method

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Does anyone know of a way to include an orWhere in a relationship to allow more than one value to match the key?

An example is we have a Product model and the Product can be a child of another Product (parent_id) and we want to pull the items from both the product and the parent.

For the relationship we may want:

```
public function items()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Item::class)
               ->orWhere('product_id', $this->parent_id);
}
```

The above example works on matching the product_id against the id and parent_id but devolves quickly when we try to do more with that relationship because it does not nest the where call.

So the SQL would be: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE product_id = x OR product_id = y`

So when we do something like `$product->items()->where('value', '>', 1);` it will break the relationship because it does:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE product_id = x OR product_id = y AND value > 1
```

instead of:

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (product_id = x OR product_id = y) AND value > 1
```

We have a workaround without utilizing an Eloquent relationship (merging two collections), but I would like to take advantage of a relationship method if possible.

Comment: ->whereIn('product_id', [1, 2, n])?

Comment: No, even using `orWhereIn('product_id', [$this->id, $this->parent_id])` that wouldn't work because it still won't evaluate the `value > 1` for any that matches the `product_id = x`

Comment: I believe it is misuse of Relationships. They meant to join by some key, it may has many values in destination table, but they all will be linked by one ID in source table.
For your case you just do: `Item::whereIn('X', [1,2,n])->where('value', 'Y')`

Comment: Yeah, maybe it makes more sense for this to be a scope, not a relationship.

Comment: Yep.
(11 more chars, damn it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Danny commented, it's a misuse of the `hasMany` relationship, merging `$product->items` and `$product->parent->items` relations would be more appropriate. However, if you want a workaround solution, you may create the relationship manually :

```
public function items() // I would rather create another method for this specific relationship
{
    $foreignKey = $this->getForeignKey();

    $instance = new Item;

    $localKey = $this->getKeyName();

    $hasMany = new \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany(
        $instance->newQuery()->whereRaw('(true'),
        $this,
        $instance->getTable().'.'.$foreignKey,
        $localKey
    );

    return $hasMany->orwhereRaw('product_id = ? )', [$this->parent_id]);
}
```

So your query would be

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE (true and product_id = x OR product_id = y) AND value > 1
```

I can't figure out how to remove the useless `true` condition, Laravel keeps adding `and` keyword behind the scene.